# How will get Offset using in react-native?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, cheerio

I m using this module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cheerio

Code

```
$(p).offset();
```

> error typeerror $(...).offset(...) is undefined

or

Can you tell me how to get offset from this https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

or

if we have any other solution, Can you give to me ?